# AWS NIC Cloudformation and Tagging

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

Is it possible to tag the embedded NIC in AWS with cloudformation? If not, is it possible to disable the embedded NIC and create a new resource and attach the NIC to the instance as ID 0 or the only network interface?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to tag network interfaces in CloudFormation:

This is an example from [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-network-interface.html) with the key/value pair foo/bar:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Simple Standalone ENI
Resources:
  myENI:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface
    Properties:
      Tags:
      - Key: foo
        Value: bar
      Description: A nice description.
      SourceDestCheck: 'false'
      GroupSet:
      - sg-75zzz219
      SubnetId: subnet-3z648z53
      PrivateIpAddress: 10.0.0.16
```

However, it is not possible to tag the embedded network interface, as per [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-network-iface-embedded.html).
However, you should be able to use the Property `DeviceIndex` to achieve your ordering. This is an adapted example from the documentation:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Simple Standalone ENI
Resources:
  Ec2Instance: 
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
    Properties: 
      ImageId: 
        Fn::FindInMap: 
          - "RegionMap"
          - Ref: "AWS::Region"
          - "AMI"
      KeyName: 
        Ref: "KeyName"
      NetworkInterfaces: 
        - AssociatePublicIpAddress: "true"
          DeviceIndex: "0"
          GroupSet: 
            - Ref: "myVPCEC2SecurityGroup"
          SubnetId: 
            Ref: "PublicSubnet"
```